# Refer to derived's class getter without actually creating this class object in java

Tags: java

Writing my small project I wanted to create object based on Factory Design Patter, which mean I have fallowing classes:

```
public abstract class A {

private int price;
private int weight;


** getters and setters**
}
```

and few classes that extends `class A` with its own values in fields `price` and `weight`, like:

```
public class B extends A {

public B(){

    setPrice(5);
    setWeight(5);
    }
}
```

And in another class, that isn't actually connected to neither to A or B I'd like to refer to `Class B` field without actually creating new object right now (I want to create new objects dynamically, when the time comes), like

```
public class C {

    public MyMethod(){
       B.getPrice();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work that way. So I managed to make variables and getters in `class A` static:

```
public abstract class A {

static private int price;
static private int weight;


static public int getPrice() {
    return price;
    }
}
```

But now, when I call `MyMethod` from `class B` I get `0` instead of `5`, which means it's result from `class A`, not `class B`.

Is there any way to get proper result of `B.getPrice()` method, without creating `class B` object in `class C`?

Comment: Where is your factory?

Comment: Class C is supossed to be factory, but right now I' trying to solve this problem.

Comment: To be more specific, I want to create something like this:
`if(x>B.getPrice(){return new B();}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what you want, is that the value of the price, is a constant value in the constructor, which means it only exists in accessible memory  after creating an instance of `B`.

You could make it a static field of `B`, and use that instead:

```
class B {
    public static final price = 5;

    public B(){
        setPrice(price);
        setWeight(5);
    }
}
```

...

```
public MyMethod(){
    B.price;
}
```

---

But if `B` really is an empty class like that, I would just remove it, make `A` non-abstract, and return a new instance of `A` from the factory.

`A` also seems to be a data class, so I would make it immutable:

```
class A {

    private final int price;
    private final int weight;

    public A(int price, int weight) {
        this.price = price;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    //... getters
}
```

...

```
public A myMethod() {
    ...
    return new A(5, 5);
    ...
}
```

If you would want the instance to still have a name, you could use a `Map<String, A>` and map the name to the instance.